# Why is this program having a runtime crash when I push data?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, segmentation-fault, stack

I am creating a stack. But when trying to push data into the stack it is having a runtime crash.Can you explain why is this happening and provide me the correct code? This is my program-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct ArrayStack* create_stack(void);
int IsStackFull(struct ArrayStack *);
int IsStackEmpty(struct ArrayStack *);

struct ArrayStack * push(struct ArrayStack *,int );
struct ArrayStack
{
   int capacity;
   int top;
   int *array;
};


int main()
{
  int choice1=0;
  int choice=0,data=0,var=0;
  struct ArrayStack *s=create_stack();

  printf("\n STACK CREATED");

  do
  {
    printf("\n 1= Test If Stack Is Empty or not");
    printf("\n 2= Test If Stack Is Full Or Not");
    printf("\n 3= Push Element Into The Stack");
    printf("\n 4= Pop Element from the stack");
    printf("\n\n Enter yOur choice:: ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
      case 1: 
      {
        var=IsStackEmpty(s);
        if(var)
        {
          printf("\n Yes Stack Is eMpty for Now");
          break;
        }
        else
        {
          printf("\n No Stack Is Not Empty ");
          break;
        }
      }

      case 2:
      {
        var=IsStackFull(s);
        if(var)
        {
          printf("\n Yes Stack Is Full for Now");
          break;
        }
        else
        {
          printf("\n No Stack Is Not Full ");
          break;
        }
      }

      case 3:
      {
        printf("\n Provide The Input For stack::");
        scanf("%d",&data);
        struct ArrayStack *s=push(s,data);
        printf("\n Element inerted into the Stack");
        break;
      } 

      case 4:
      {
        var=pop(s);
        if(var)
        {
          printf("\n Removed The element from the Stack");
          break;
        }
        break;
      }

      default:
      {
        printf("\n Wrong Input");
      }  
    }
    printf("\n Do you want to countinue(1 for yes/0 for no):: ");
    scanf("%d",&choice1);
  }while(choice1); 
}

struct ArrayStack* create_stack()
{
  struct ArrayStack *s=(struct ArrayStack *)malloc(sizeof(struct ArrayStack));
  if(!s)
  {
    printf("\nNot enough Memory");
    return NULL;
  }
  s->capacity=4;
  s->top=-1;

  s->array=(int *)malloc(s->capacity*sizeof(int));
  if(!s->array)
  {
    return NULL;
  }
  else
    return s;
}


int IsStackEmpty(struct ArrayStack *s)
{
  if(s->top=-1)
    return 1;
  else 
    return 0;
}

int IsStackFull(struct ArrayStack *s)
{
  if(s->top==s->capacity-1)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

struct ArrayStack * push(struct ArrayStack *s,int data)
{
  if(IsStackFull(s))
  {
    printf("\n Sorry. The stack is full already");
  }
  else
  {
    s->array[++s->top]=data;
    printf("\n Element Inserted Successfully");
    return s;
  }
}

int pop(struct ArrayStack *s)
{
  if(IsStackEmpty(s))
  {
    printf("\n Sorry. Trying to pop element from an empty stack");
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    s->array=s->array[s->top--];
    return 1;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Newbies are most welcome (We all were newbies afterall). Downvotes happen because the question does not include proper error message (What the compiler produces), the input , the expected and the observed output. And for complete codes atleast a rough idea of what the code is expected to do

Comment: It compiles fine. There is a runtime crash when I m trying to push the data.

Comment: @VusP Downvotes can also happen if the asker didn't debug to narrow down the issue, the provided code is too long (both of which could apply in this case), or a variety of other reasons.

Comment: @Dukeling I agree with that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Push element case, you are creating one local instance of `s`, which is confusing with s you have created before `do..while` loop.

Change code in switch case 3 to

```
s=push(s,data); //(remove struct ArrayStack *)
```

Comment: There is also a similar problem while popping the elements from the stack. I cannot find the error. Would you please help me out?

Comment: @Arindrajit I think there is some problem with _s->array=s->array[s->top--];_

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` test in `IsStackEmpty()` is doomed. With

```
if(s->top=-1)
```

You are assigning instead of comparing. This always evaluates to true, so your `IsStackEmpty()` function always says the stack is empty. Use `==` instead.

Your `pop` function is wrong. You don't want to change the pointer returned by `malloc`, given your structure definition, I believe you would want to decrement `top`, and return the popped element (notice you never return the popped element...)

```
int pop(struct ArrayStack *s)
{
 if(IsStackEmpty(s))
 {
   printf("\n Sorry. Trying to pop element from an empty stack");
   return 0;
 }
 else
 {
   return s->top--;
 } 
}
```

This assumes that `0` is never pushed, so you can distinguish error conditions from normal flow. Otherwise, you'll have to find some other way to report errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
case 3:
   {
     printf("\n Provide The Input For stack::");
     scanf("%d",&data);
     struct ArrayStack *s=push(s,data);
     printf("\n Element inerted into the Stack");
     break;
    }
```

In above code, ArrayStack **s** is not initialised and it is used in IsStackEmpty() functions , so it crashes with access violation, use the ArrayStack **s** already initialised in main program using Create_Stack()

```
 struct ArrayStack *s=create_stack();
```